# How to bind live data to array adapter android

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a simple application while I'm trying to understand android/room. I would like to have my query from room to be placed into my list view.

PersonDao.class

```
@Query("Select name from People limit 3")
LiveData<List<String>> getThreeNames();
```

AvtivityMain.class

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

private PersonDatabase db;
private EditText age;
private EditText name;
Person person;
private DatabaseRepository rDb;
private PersonViewModel personViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    ListView lvPerson = findViewById(R.id.lv3Poeple);
    lvPerson.setAdapter(adapter);
    personViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PersonViewModel.class);

}

public void addPerson(View view){
    int sAge = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
    String sName = name.getText().toString();
    person = new Person(sName, sAge);
    personViewModel.insert(person);
    System.out.println(personViewModel.getmAllPeople());
    System.out.println(personViewModel.getm3People());
    //List<String> names = personViewModel.getm3People();
    //adapter.add(personViewModel.getm3People());
}
```

I have commented out the code I am having problems with. I want to be able to use my query from PersonDao and have my list view show 3 names from my Room database.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? how does your PersonViewModel look like?

Comment: you need to attach an observer to PersonViewModel where all the changes will be reflected in onChanged method of observer and from there you can pass your data to the listview adapter and call notifydatasetchanged

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a few things, the first is make sure your adapter can take new input. I would suggest creating your own custom one. When you do create it, be sure to include a method that takes your person strings as input and notifies the adapter of the change, like so:

```
//you need to add an update method to your adapter, so it can change it's data as your
//viewmodel data changes, something like this:
public void setPersons(List<String> personNames) {
    //myPersons should be a variable declared within your adapter that the views load info from
    myPersons = personNames;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in your activity you should set the Adapter as a global variable so it can be accessed by multiple methods, such as your view model observer method and it's initial setup in `onCreate()`.

```
//need to set up adapter variable to access in other methods to keep view model observer
//off the main thread
private ArrayAdapter myAdapter;
```

After that you can set up the following observer method for your `ViewModel` (assuming you created the ViewModel Class properly with a return method called `getThreeNames()` and that isn't just within your DAO as you showed above.

```
//set up the view model observer to be off the main thread so it isn't tied to your main
//activity lifecyle (which is the whole point/beauty of the ViewModel), you can call this
//method in your onCreate() method and should stay until onDestroy() is called
private void setupPersonViewModel() {
    PersonViewModel viewModel
            = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PersonViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getThreeNames().observe(this, new Observer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<String> persons) {
            //so you can see when your app does this in your log
            Log.d(TAG, "Updating list of persons from LiveData in ViewModel");
            mAdapter.setPersons(persons);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that answers your question. Let me know if you need any further clarification.